# Does the std::sqrt function in c++ slow down as the number gets larger?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing my own maths library and currently I need to normalize vectors and quaternions.

Performance is going to be a big issue for me and thus I've been wondering, because my numbers can possibly extend to quite high limits, does the `std::sqrt` function in C++ perform slower and slower as the size of the number increases or will it always execute in the same amount of time?

This question is specifically related to the performance in C++11.

Comment: C++ provides no guarantees either way. Rather than hypothesise about performance, the best strategy is to measure it by profiling your code on realistic inputs.

Comment: Test it. I wouldn't anticipate much difference in timing, but it's possible. Also, any difference is probably not going to be monotonically related to increases in the value of the input. Instead, if there's any difference, it will probably be that values that are slower or faster to process are scattered 'randomly' over the whole range. Perhaps with performance differing between different classes of values, such as denormalized floats being slower than normalized floats on average.

Comment: That makes sense, well I'll do that and post the results here when I'm done.

Comment: There's no noticeable difference.

Comment: There may be optimizations for very small numbers but it should make no difference, if the number is medium sized or large.

Comment: This depends much more on hardware than on language. Most compilers and interpreters will ultimately use `FSQRT` assembler instruction.

Comment: @TNA: For (very) small numbers the time needed is actually bigger. For x<1, sqrt(x) > x. E.g. sqrt(1/4) = 1/2. Now if x is denormal, then sqrt(x) is a regular number >0 . That can't be optimized to 0. So you would in fact expect sqrt(x) to slow down for _small_ numbers, not big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, no.

Floating point numbers on moderns systems are represented as a sign, exponent and mantissa. The sign here must be 0, that's easy. Take two numbers, `x` and `4*x`. The only difference in their representation is that the exponent of the second is 2 higher. (unless at the extreme of ranges, `4*x` could be `+INF` but let's ignore that.)

Now `sqrt(4*x) == 2 * sqrt(x)` and we here see that the exponent of the result is one higher, but the mantissa is the same.

This means that the time needed to calculate the square root does not significantly depend on the exponent of the number. You just factor out `4^n` in constant time. The hard part of `sqrt(x)` is calculating the mantissa of the result, and that just depends on two things: the mantissa of the input and whether the input exponent is odd.

Answer (score 0):

for naked eyes, its no.. or I will say very small difference..

if you are worried about your own implementation I will suggest you to implement the

```
 Babylonian Method for Square Root  --> it is much faster then others..
```

[Babylonian Method on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)

few other links for babyionian

http://mathlesstraveled.com/2009/05/18/square-roots-with-pencil-and-paper-the-babylonian-method/

http://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/square-root-algorithm.php

Comment: The babylonian method won't beat hardware.

Comment: First time I've heard this called the Baylonian method; it looks like the Newton–Raphson method to me.  And its performance depends very much on how good your first guess is.  (But as @MSalters says, even with a very good first guess, it won't beat hardware.)

Comment: beating hardware is different thing.. @MSalters have I ever said it will beat hardware?? ;) yes.. James u r right.. it depends upon ur first guess..